# Taking the mean by one column and then by another in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset:

```
   data =  {'VALVE_SCORE': {0: 34.1,1: 41.0,2: 49.7,3: 53.8,4: 35.8,5: 49.2,6: 38.6,7: 51.2,8: 44.8,9: 51.5,10: 41.9,11: 46.0,12: 41.9,13: 51.4,14: 35.0,15: 49.7,16: 41.5,17: 51.5,18: 45.2,19: 53.4,20: 38.1,21: 50.2,22: 25.4,23: 30.0,24: 28.1,25: 49.9,26: 27.5,27: 37.2,28: 27.7,29: 45.7,30: 27.2,31: 30.0,32: 27.9,33: 34.3,34: 29.5,35: 34.5,36: 28.0,37: 33.6,38: 26.8,39: 31.8},
     'DAY': {0: 6, 1: 6, 2: 6, 3: 6, 4: 13, 5: 13, 6: 13, 7: 13, 8: 20, 9: 20, 10: 20, 11: 20, 12: 27, 13: 27, 14: 27, 15: 27, 16: 3, 17: 3, 18: 3, 19: 3, 20: 10, 21: 10, 22: 10, 23: 10, 24: 17, 25: 17, 26: 17, 27: 17, 28: 24, 29: 24, 30: 24, 31: 24, 32: 3, 33: 3, 34: 3, 35: 3, 36: 10, 37: 10, 38: 10, 39: 10},
     'MONTH': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1, 10: 1, 11: 1, 12: 1, 13: 1, 14: 1, 15: 1, 16: 2, 17: 2, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 2, 21: 2, 22: 2, 23: 2, 24: 2, 25: 2, 26: 2, 27: 2, 28: 2, 29: 2, 30: 2, 31: 2, 32: 3, 33: 3, 34: 3, 35: 3, 36: 3, 37: 3, 38: 3, 39: 3}}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

First, I would like to take the `mean` by day and then by month. However, taking the mean by grouping the days results in decimal months. I would like to preserve the months before I do a `groupby('MONTH').mean()`

```
In [401]: df.groupby("DAY").mean()
Out[401]: 
       VALVE_SCORE  MONTH
DAY                
3    39.7250    2.5
6    44.6500    1.0
10   32.9875    2.5
13   43.7000    1.0
17   35.6750    2.0
20   46.0500    1.0
24   32.6500    2.0
27   44.5000    1.0
```

I would like the end result to be:

```
MONTH  VALVE_SCORE
1      value
2      value
3      value
```

Comment: Can someone care to explain why the question gets a negative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider with the data you have, you would like to have the daily mean and then the monthly mean. Putting the same in an Excel pivot table will result like this:

[image]

Do doing the same in pandas, grouping by months is enough to get the same result:

```
df.groupby(['MONTH']).mean()
        DAY  VALVE_SCORE
MONTH
1      16.5      44.7250
2      13.5      38.0375
3       6.5      30.8000
```

Since the month and day values are numeric, pandas process it, consider 'DAY' and 'MONTH' values are not numeric and are strings, you get this result:

```
       VALVE_SCORE
MONTH
1          44.7250
2          38.0375
3          30.8000
```

So pandas already computes the daily means and using it computes the monthly means.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution. Do let me know if there is a more efficient way of doing it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

months = list(df['MONTH'].unique())

frames = []
for p in months:
  df_part = df[df['MONTH'] == p]
  df_part_avg = df_part.groupby("DAY", as_index=False).mean()
  df_part_avg = df_part_avg.drop('DAY', axis=1)
  frames.append(df_part_avg)

df_months = pd.concat(frames)
df_final = df_months.groupby("MONTH", as_index=False).mean()
```

And the result is:

```
In [430]: df_final
Out[430]: 
   MONTH  VALVE_SCORE
0      1      44.7250
1      2      38.0375
2      3      30.8000
```